# How to retrieve user data from djoser endpoint (.../users/me)

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, djoser

How do I retrieve users info from using djoser url `/users/me/`? I tried to follow the example in this documentation but nothing works out, I keep getting 403 forbidden. I used `Bearer, JWT, and Token` in the authorization header but none of them worked.
https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/base_endpoints.html

[image]

```
SETTINGS.PY

DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SET_USERNAME_RETYPE': True,
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'current_user': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings

Comment: @shafik, pls check, I have added djoser setting in settings.py

Comment: Did u add `REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        (...)
    ),
}`

Comment: Yes, I added the authentication class to the settings

Comment: Did ur problem solved?

Comment: No, it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Create new UserSerializer class for users by inheriting from djoser UserSerializer
and add settings
`'SERIALIZERS': {'user': 'accounts.serializers.UserSerializer', 'current_user': 'accounts.serializers.UserSerializer'}`